# Organization ID: cannot specify Id in an insert call

Tags: apex, visualforce

When I enter account name in page it auto populate field on page. But it gives error when I click on submit.How to resolve it?

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="prevHostApplicationController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

    <script>
        function OpenAddCon(event){
        alert('in here');
        document.getElementById('addcon1').style.display = 'block';
        event.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>

    <apex:form id="fmId">       
        <apex:actionFunction name="sayHello" action="{!ActionFunMethode}" rerender="out" status="myStatus"/>        
        <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
        <div style="height:30px;border-radius:12px;margin:auto;width:70%;background-color: grey;color:white;font-size:18px;font-family:calibri">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Organization information</div>
        <apex:outputPanel id="panel1" >
            <apex:actionRegion >
                <table style="width:70%;margin:auto;">
                    <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-01">*Name</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField label="*Name" styleClass="slds-input" id="out" value="{!Account.Name}" > 
                                <apex:actionSupport action="{!fetchAccount}" event="onchange" reRender="panel1" status="searching"/>
                            </apex:inputfield>                                                       
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-04">*Website</label>              
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField label="Website" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Account.Website}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-01">*Phone </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField label="Phone" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Account.Phone}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-04">*Organization Headquarters :</label>              
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField label="Organization Headquarters" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Account.Organization_Locations__c}"/>
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-01">*No of Employees</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField label="No of Employees" value="{!Account.No_of_Employees__c}"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-04">*City</label>            
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField label="City" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Account.BillingCity}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" >*Street address</label>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField style="size:unset;"  label="Street address" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" />              
                        </td>

                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" >*Country</label>

                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField label="Country" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Account.BillingCountry}" />         
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" >*State</label>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField label="State" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Account.BillingState}" />

                        </td>

                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                        <td>
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-04">*Postal Code</label>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <apex:inputField label="Postal Code" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
                </table>
            </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <div style="height:30px;border-radius:12px;margin:auto;width:70%;background-color: grey;color:white;font-size:18px;font-family:calibri">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Primary Contact</div>
        <br/>
        <table style="width:70%;margin:auto;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" >*First Name :</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputField label="First Name" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-04">*Contact preference</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputField styleClass="slds-input" value="{!contact.Contact_Preference__c}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
            <tr>    
                <td>
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" >*Last Name :</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputField label="Last Name" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Contact.LastName}"/>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-04">*Job Title :</label>              
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputField label="Website" styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Contact.Title}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" >*Skype Account</label>             
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputField styleClass="slds-input" value="{!contact.Skype_Account__c}"/>
                </td> 
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>   

                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
            </tr>

            <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
            <tr>    
                <td>
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" >How does your company fund its operations?</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputField styleClass="slds-input" value="{!Project.How_does_your_company_fund_its_operation__c}" />
                </td>

            </tr>  
            <tr><td><br/></td></tr>

            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </table>
        <tr><td><br/></td></tr>

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div style="padding-left: 740px">

            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" style="background-color:Blue" value="Submit" rerender=""/>
            <apex:commandButton style="background-color:Blue" value="Cancel"/>

        </div> 
        <apex:actionStatus id="searching">                   
            <apex:facet name="start">
                <div class="waitingSearchDiv waitingSearchDivOpacity" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; opacity: 0.80" />        
                <div id="searchingStatus" class="waitingSearchDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
                    <div class="waitingHolder" style="top: 300px; width: 110px;">
                        <img class="waitingImage" src="/img/loading.gif"/>
                        <span class="waitingDescription">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:facet name="stop"/>
        </apex:actionStatus>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class prevHostApplicationController {
    public Contact contact{get;set;}
    public Contact contact1{get;set;}
    public List<String> listOfStrings {get; set;}
    //public String targetField { get; set;}

    public Account account{get;set;}
    public Project__c project{get;set;}
    public List<Project__c> listProjects{get;set;}
    public blob file{get; set;}

    public void fetchAccount() {
        List<Account> temp = new list<Account>();
        temp = [SELECT Id, Name, Website, Phone, Organization_Locations__c, No_of_Employees__c, 
                BillingCity, BillingStreet, BillingCountry, BillingState, BillingPostalCode                
                FROM Account Where Name =: Account.Name];

        if(temp.size()>0) {
            Account = temp[0];
        } else {
            string name = Account.Name;
            Account = new Account();
            Account.Name = name;
        }
    }

    public prevHostApplicationController() {
        contact = new Contact();
        account = new Account();
        project = new Project__c();
        contact1 = new Contact();        
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        try {
            insert account;
            contact.accountId = account.Id;
            insert contact;
            insert contact1;

            project.Organization__c= account.Id;
            insert project;
            upload();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Created Successfully.Thank you!'));
        }        
        return null;
    }

    public Attachment attachment {
        get {
            if (attachment == null)
                attachment = new Attachment();            
            return attachment;
        }
        set;
    }

    public PageReference upload() {
        attachment.Name='tesing by me';
        attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        attachment.ParentId = project.id; // the record the file is attached to
        attachment.IsPrivate = true;

        try {
            insert attachment;
        } catch (DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
            return null;
        } finally {
            //attachment = new Attachment(); 
        }

        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));
        return null;
    }

    public string ActionFunMethode() {
        listOfStrings = new list<String>();
        for(Account a:[SELECT id,name from Account limit 1])
            listOfStrings.add(a.name);        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Error:

> Organization ID: cannot specify Id in an insert call

Comment: `ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Created Successfully.Thank you!'));` -- no, it has not been created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to specify id in an insert call if you want to use same code for update and insert use upsert instead of insert